# Is there a type of report or cross-tab that would display this data elegantly?

Tags: database, crystal-reports, reporting

I have data in this form,

```
Article ID  Company A   Company B   Company C
1            Featured    Mentioned   --
2            Mentioned   Featured    Mentioned
3            Mentioned   --          --
4            Featured    Mentioned   Mentioned
5            Mentioned   Mentioned   Featured
```

I’d like to show, for example, how many times Company B was mentioned in an article where Company A was featured.  I can write a manual query to answer that, however, I thought perhaps there’s a more elegant way to show in a grid the counts of all combinations.  Someone could then see how many times Company C was mentioned in an article where Company A or B was featured, and vice versa.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this?  I’m just not feeling creative today and all I can think of is the lame, brute-force, manual method ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could add a filter drop-down on each column, like the auto-filter in Excel, the users could select 'Mentioned' for Company A and 'Featured' for Company B and the number of rows displayed would be the answer to the "how many" question.